# Why is my code for keyword extraction from Twitter not printing anything?

Tags: python, json, nlp, rake, twitter-streaming-api

I am trying to build a keyword extractor that extracts keywords from tweets through TwitterStream but nothing happens when I run this code, no error and no output it just keeps running.

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json
from rake_nltk import Rake


#consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
ckey=""
csecret=""
atoken=""
asecret=""

r = Rake() # Uses stopwords for english from NLTK, and all puntuation characters.


class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:

            all_data = json.loads(data)

            tweet = all_data["text"]
            r.extract_keywords_from_text(tweet)
            r.get_ranked_phrases()
            return True
        except:
            return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=['news'])
```

Comment: With a debugger or just by adding some print, you should be able to tell what the program does and if it get stuck somewhere. Did you try?

Comment: Yeah I did, it doesn't do the part of code in the true: part it always goes for the except: case